# How tty driver interacts with UART driver during read/write opetations?

Tags: linux, driver, tty, uart

I am working on modification/development of a SDIO UART driver.
And would like to know:

How tty driver interacts with UART driver during read/write operations? I am interested in buffer management.

I searched over net, however did not find necessary information.
Can somebody throw some light on this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "tty"? The driver? A real TTY terminal?

Comment: @Jim Garrison: Can you please explain the difference? BTW: I meant tty driver. Thank you.

Comment: @Jim Garrison: I've made the appropriate change in the title and question. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following links helped me understand TTY layer operations. TTY driver's read/write operations are little tricky to understand though..

1. [tty Layer (2.4)](http://marcocorvi.altervista.org/games/lkpe/tty/tty.htm)
2. [The tty Layer](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/5896)
3. [The tty Layer, Part II](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6226)